# SharePoint extend ALL fieldproperties with custom settings

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, field

What is want is pretty simple. 
I want to add settings to all field-properties (oob and custom) in a custom listdefinition, say "E-mailform". Thus, I create a "E-mailform" and I add a OOB-textfield. At the settingspage (where you can set length, required yes/no, etc.) I want to add a custom section with custom settings. When I add a OOB-numberfield, I want to add this same custom section.

I use SharePoint lists to create webforms and I have adapted the NewForm.aspx to show it in the required layout. However, I have to add settings to the fields, e.g. to make fields appear next to each other instead of all below each other.
Thus, I have to extend all field settings with a custom "emailform-property-setting".

I have Googled a lot and the only solution i found is to make custom fields, but that is not what I want...

I hope I explained it well enough!

Comment: What you want doesn't sound simple? I've never heard of anything like this being possible. It seems to me you want to change OOB behaviour that was never meant to be changeable. What is it that you are trying to achieve? Change the layout of the newform.aspx?

Comment: Hey! I already have a custom newform.aspx (mailform.aspx) with custom rendering. I however want add extra rendering properties to ALL fields. E.g. I want to set a property on a field "align: right", such that it will float to the right. I want to stay as close as possible to OOB SharePoint end therefore want to extend the custom field properties screen.

Comment: ... A solution is to build a custom Layoutpage, bound to a list, which let me set all these properties, but I want to avoid this if possible. I hope it's clear now what I want.